# save outlook attachments with python

Tags: python, outlook

Every Monday I receive the attachments with the  slightly  changed subject title. Constant part of the subject title is **PB Report** and will have the Monday's date. For example I received email this Monday with subject **PB Report - 13.12.2021**, last week **PB Report - 06.12.2021** and so on. I would like to implement the `GetLast` in this code in order to get only the newest sent report. Also, how do I tell python to search the subject which starts with PB Report and dont look at the rest of the title. I tried wildcard(*) as `save_attachments('PB Report*')` but did not work.

```
import datetime
import os
import win32com.client

path = r"C:/Users/greencolor/Desktop/Autoreport/"
today = datetime.date.today()

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items


def save_attachments(subject):
    for message in messages:
        if message.Subject == subject:
            for attachment in message.Attachments:
                print(attachment.FileName)
                attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(path, str(attachment)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    save_attachments('PB Report - 13.12.2021')
```

I also have the alternative code but when i run this code i never get the result  nor error. It takes.

```
import os
import win32com.client
    
path = r"C:/Users/greencolor/Desktop/Autoreport/"
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()


while message:
    if 'PB' in message.subject and 'Report' in message.subject:
        for attachment in message.Attachments:
            print(attachment.FileName)
            attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(path, str(attachment)))
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail: What is your main question (among 3 asked) ? What is the current issue with your code? Please describe _what_ did not work, what was expected and what was the actual output/behavior.

Comment: main question is how to download the multiple attachments (attached in the newest email) from outlook by searching with subject name (but  50% of the subject is changing always).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wildcard for parameter `subject` wont work because parameter `subject` is used as string when comparing for equality in `message.Subject == subject`.

You could instead use string-method `startswith` on the message subject like `message.Subject.startswith(subject_prefix)`
and call your method with a common prefix like `save_attachments('PB Report - ')`.

Furthermore use the `attachment.FileName` to construct the output-file path.

You could use `GetLast()` or `Sort()` with appropriate message property to filter on the *newest sent report*. Or you could parse the dates in message's subject and sort them accordingly. However this would deserve another question, own research and further specification and focus.

#### Solution

An example solution could be as follows (see comments for adjustments):

```py
def save_attachments(subject_prefix): # changed parameter name
    messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)  # sort by received date: newest to oldest 
    for message in messages:
        if message.Subject.startswith(subject_prefix): # changed test
            print("saving attachments for:", message.Subject)
            for attachment in message.Attachments:
                print(attachment.FileName)
                attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(path, str(attachment.FileName)))  # changed to file-name
            return  # exit after first matched message
```

Alternatively use `GetLast()` if you know the messages only contain desired ones, sorted by date.

```py
message = messages.GetLast()
while message:  # to test if there is a (last) message at all
    # save attachment
```

#### Related questions

- [str.startswith with a list of strings to test for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461847/str-startswith-with-a-list-of-strings-to-test-for)
- [Search the entire Outlook email box for specific emails using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68764496/search-the-entire-outlook-email-box-for-specific-emails-using-python)
- [How to go through Outlook emails in reverse order using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42428770/how-to-go-through-outlook-emails-in-reverse-order-using-python)

Comment: Thank you so much it works very good and its faster then what I had above (above one only was saving if i would have full title). I just have little problem. It download the the images attached in the email signature too. I just only need to download excel files